# Laravel, order by related model SUM

Tags: laravel

I have a belongsToMany relationship between a 'users' and 'media' table.

I would like to display in my view the medias in the order of 'like' sum (=the popularity of each media) with pagination. For example the media which has received the biggest number of likes among the user is displayed first.

My DB :

```
  'media' : id, name
  'media_user' : id, media_id, user_id, like 
  'users' id, name
```

'like is not a boolean but an integer but an integer, it can be -1 etc... I want to sum it.

I have in my User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function medias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Media')->withPivot('like')->withTimestamps();
    }

    ...
}
```

I have seen something like this in another post but I cannot make it work...

```
$medias=Media::leftJoin(
    DB::raw('(SELECT media_id, SUM(like) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v'),
    'v.media_id', '=', 'media.id'
)->orderBy('likes', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

Below is the exception I get with the above query

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'like) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v on v.media_id = medi' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from media` inner join (SELECT media_id, SUM(like) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v on v.media_id = media.id)

Thank you!

Comment: How / why isn't it working? i.e Are you getting an error? Are you not getting any results? Are you getting results but not the ones you expected?

Comment: Below is the exception I get with the $medias=Media::leftJoin I wrote in the original post:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'like) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v on `v`.`media_id` = `medi' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `media` inner join (SELECT media_id, SUM(like) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v on `v`.`media_id` = `media`.`id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine its because your column name is `like` which is a reserved key word.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/

Try wrapping `like` in backticks:

```
$medias = Media::leftJoin(
    DB::raw('(SELECT media_id, SUM(`like`) AS likes FROM media_user GROUP BY media_id) as v'),
    'v.media_id', '=', 'media.id'
)->orderBy('likes', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

Hope this helps!